# Subsetting lists via logical index vectors

Tags: r, indexing, vectorization, subset, nested-lists

I have a **complex list** and need to select a *subset* from it, based on the value of a boolean element (I need records with `hidden` value equal to `FALSE`). I've tried the following code, based on *index vectors*, but it fails (as shown at the end of this output):

```
startups <- data$startups[data$startups$hidden == FALSE]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
startups <- data$startups[!as.logical(data$startups$hidden)]
```

Interactive R session proves that the data is there:

```
Browse[1]> str(data$startups, list.len=3)
List of 50
 $ :List of 23
  ..$ id               : num 357496
  ..$ hidden           : logi FALSE
  ..$ community_profile: logi FALSE
  .. [list output truncated]
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ id    : num 352159
  ..$ hidden: logi TRUE
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ id    : num 352157
  ..$ hidden: logi TRUE
  [list output truncated]

Browse[1]> data$startups[data$startups$hidden == FALSE]
list()

Browse[1]> data$startups[!as.logical(data$startups$hidden)]
list()
```

What is the problem with my code?

**Update (hopefully includes reproducible example, sorry about the complex structure)**

`aa <- dput(head(data$startups, n=3))`

produces the following output:

```
list(structure(list(id = 386938, hidden = FALSE, community_profile = FALSE, 
    name = "Pritunl", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/pritunl", 
    logo_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/386938-fac0b8cba76c7e9252eee6646ec5b681-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1398401450", 
    thumb_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/386938-fac0b8cba76c7e9252eee6646ec5b681-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1398401450", 
    quality = 0, product_desc = "Enterprise VPN/cloud networking server", 
    high_concept = "Enterprise cloud networking", follower_count = 1, 
    company_url = "http://pritunl.com", created_at = "2014-04-25T04:50:57Z", 
    updated_at = "2014-04-25T06:02:05Z", crunchbase_url = NULL, 
    twitter_url = "http://twitter.com/pritunl", blog_url = "", 
    video_url = "", markets = list(structure(list(id = 12, tag_type = "MarketTag", 
        name = "enterprise software", display_name = "Enterprise Software", 
        angellist_url = "https://angel.co/enterprise-software"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url")), structure(list(
        id = 59, tag_type = "MarketTag", name = "open source", 
        display_name = "Open Source", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/open-source"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url")), structure(list(
        id = 123, tag_type = "MarketTag", name = "internet infrastructure", 
        display_name = "Internet Infrastructure", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/internet-infrastructure"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url")), structure(list(
        id = 306, tag_type = "MarketTag", name = "cloud management", 
        display_name = "Cloud Management", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/cloud-management"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url"))), locations = list(
        structure(list(id = 2071, tag_type = "LocationTag", name = "new york", 
            display_name = "New York", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/new-york"), .Names = c("id", 
        "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url"))), 
    company_size = "1-10", company_type = list(structure(list(
        id = 94212, tag_type = "CompanyTypeTag", name = "startup", 
        display_name = "Startup", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/startup"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url"))), status = NULL, 
    screenshots = list(structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/5f7410543201d583eaba1975b931f3fd-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/5f7410543201d583eaba1975b931f3fd-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")), structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/006c4fb50d4b10df7caf7800ee482c6b-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/006c4fb50d4b10df7caf7800ee482c6b-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")), structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/741225c3de5021399c0cfc33cecb8830-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/741225c3de5021399c0cfc33cecb8830-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")), structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/969b60b6ccda577e77b7c9a5c169b2fd-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/969b60b6ccda577e77b7c9a5c169b2fd-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")), structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/2b2cc3a046c5a4d20b328045ca7f0254-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/2b2cc3a046c5a4d20b328045ca7f0254-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")), structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/053c3a1c74fc7f39de1117770f9debef-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/053c3a1c74fc7f39de1117770f9debef-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")), structure(list(thumb = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/8adcf2d6a6cafc9c6b810f8359a3fedf-thumb_jpg.jpg", 
        original = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/8adcf2d6a6cafc9c6b810f8359a3fedf-original.png"), .Names = c("thumb", 
    "original")))), .Names = c("id", "hidden", "community_profile", 
"name", "angellist_url", "logo_url", "thumb_url", "quality", 
"product_desc", "high_concept", "follower_count", "company_url", 
"created_at", "updated_at", "crunchbase_url", "twitter_url", 
"blog_url", "video_url", "markets", "locations", "company_size", 
"company_type", "status", "screenshots")), structure(list(id = 385596, 
    hidden = FALSE, community_profile = TRUE, name = "Lariat ", 
    angellist_url = "https://angel.co/lariat-1", logo_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/385596-29de05d584176c3972da411aed5485f0-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1398260121", 
    thumb_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/385596-29de05d584176c3972da411aed5485f0-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1398260121", 
    quality = 0, product_desc = "Thus far, the internet has gone from discovery to search discovery, and then social discovery, but with little focus on recall. Remembering your digital footprint is difficult. We aim to solve that problem. Lariat is a cloud-based recall engine to securely recall information from any page in your search history instantly through intuitive keyword search, not just from page titles, but from the contents and context of the underlying pages.\r\n\r\nWrangle in the information you want, easier and faster.", 
    high_concept = "Recall your digital footprint on the web instantly", 
    follower_count = 1, company_url = "http://www.lariattech.com", 
    created_at = "2014-04-23T13:17:47Z", updated_at = "2014-04-23T13:48:38Z", 
    crunchbase_url = NULL, twitter_url = "", blog_url = "", video_url = NULL, 
    markets = list(structure(list(id = 4, tag_type = "MarketTag", 
        name = "digital media", display_name = "Digital Media", 
        angellist_url = "https://angel.co/digital-media"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url")), structure(list(
        id = 12, tag_type = "MarketTag", name = "enterprise software", 
        display_name = "Enterprise Software", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/enterprise-software"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url")), structure(list(
        id = 59, tag_type = "MarketTag", name = "open source", 
        display_name = "Open Source", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/open-source"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url")), structure(list(
        id = 282, tag_type = "MarketTag", name = "semantic search", 
        display_name = "Semantic Search", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/semantic-search"), .Names = c("id", 
    "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url"))), locations = list(
        structure(list(id = 1620, tag_type = "LocationTag", name = "boston", 
            display_name = "Boston", angellist_url = "https://angel.co/boston"), .Names = c("id", 
        "tag_type", "name", "display_name", "angellist_url"))), 
    company_size = "1-10", company_type = structure(list(), class = "AsIs"), 
    status = NULL, screenshots = structure(list(), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("id", 
"hidden", "community_profile", "name", "angellist_url", "logo_url", 
"thumb_url", "quality", "product_desc", "high_concept", "follower_count", 
"company_url", "created_at", "updated_at", "crunchbase_url", 
"twitter_url", "blog_url", "video_url", "markets", "locations", 
"company_size", "company_type", "status", "screenshots")), structure(list(
    id = 385595, hidden = TRUE), .Names = c("id", "hidden")))
```

The same in a more readable format (`aa`):

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] 386938

[[1]]$hidden
[1] FALSE

[[1]]$community_profile
[1] FALSE

[[1]]$name
[1] "Pritunl"

[[1]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/pritunl"

[[1]]$logo_url
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/386938-fac0b8cba76c7e9252eee6646ec5b681-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1398401450"

[[1]]$thumb_url
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/386938-fac0b8cba76c7e9252eee6646ec5b681-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1398401450"

[[1]]$quality
[1] 0

[[1]]$product_desc
[1] "Enterprise VPN/cloud networking server"

[[1]]$high_concept
[1] "Enterprise cloud networking"

[[1]]$follower_count
[1] 1

[[1]]$company_url
[1] "http://pritunl.com"

[[1]]$created_at
[1] "2014-04-25T04:50:57Z"

[[1]]$updated_at
[1] "2014-04-25T06:02:05Z"

[[1]]$crunchbase_url
NULL

[[1]]$twitter_url
[1] "http://twitter.com/pritunl"

[[1]]$blog_url
[1] ""

[[1]]$video_url
[1] ""

[[1]]$markets
[[1]]$markets[[1]]
[[1]]$markets[[1]]$id
[1] 12

[[1]]$markets[[1]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[1]]$markets[[1]]$name
[1] "enterprise software"

[[1]]$markets[[1]]$display_name
[1] "Enterprise Software"

[[1]]$markets[[1]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/enterprise-software"


[[1]]$markets[[2]]
[[1]]$markets[[2]]$id
[1] 59

[[1]]$markets[[2]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[1]]$markets[[2]]$name
[1] "open source"

[[1]]$markets[[2]]$display_name
[1] "Open Source"

[[1]]$markets[[2]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/open-source"


[[1]]$markets[[3]]
[[1]]$markets[[3]]$id
[1] 123

[[1]]$markets[[3]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[1]]$markets[[3]]$name
[1] "internet infrastructure"

[[1]]$markets[[3]]$display_name
[1] "Internet Infrastructure"

[[1]]$markets[[3]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/internet-infrastructure"


[[1]]$markets[[4]]
[[1]]$markets[[4]]$id
[1] 306

[[1]]$markets[[4]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[1]]$markets[[4]]$name
[1] "cloud management"

[[1]]$markets[[4]]$display_name
[1] "Cloud Management"

[[1]]$markets[[4]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/cloud-management"



[[1]]$locations
[[1]]$locations[[1]]
[[1]]$locations[[1]]$id
[1] 2071

[[1]]$locations[[1]]$tag_type
[1] "LocationTag"

[[1]]$locations[[1]]$name
[1] "new york"

[[1]]$locations[[1]]$display_name
[1] "New York"

[[1]]$locations[[1]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/new-york"



[[1]]$company_size
[1] "1-10"

[[1]]$company_type
[[1]]$company_type[[1]]
[[1]]$company_type[[1]]$id
[1] 94212

[[1]]$company_type[[1]]$tag_type
[1] "CompanyTypeTag"

[[1]]$company_type[[1]]$name
[1] "startup"

[[1]]$company_type[[1]]$display_name
[1] "Startup"

[[1]]$company_type[[1]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/startup"



[[1]]$status
NULL

[[1]]$screenshots
[[1]]$screenshots[[1]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[1]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/5f7410543201d583eaba1975b931f3fd-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[1]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/5f7410543201d583eaba1975b931f3fd-original.png"


[[1]]$screenshots[[2]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[2]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/006c4fb50d4b10df7caf7800ee482c6b-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[2]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/006c4fb50d4b10df7caf7800ee482c6b-original.png"


[[1]]$screenshots[[3]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[3]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/741225c3de5021399c0cfc33cecb8830-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[3]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/741225c3de5021399c0cfc33cecb8830-original.png"


[[1]]$screenshots[[4]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[4]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/969b60b6ccda577e77b7c9a5c169b2fd-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[4]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/969b60b6ccda577e77b7c9a5c169b2fd-original.png"


[[1]]$screenshots[[5]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[5]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/2b2cc3a046c5a4d20b328045ca7f0254-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[5]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/2b2cc3a046c5a4d20b328045ca7f0254-original.png"


[[1]]$screenshots[[6]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[6]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/053c3a1c74fc7f39de1117770f9debef-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[6]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/053c3a1c74fc7f39de1117770f9debef-original.png"


[[1]]$screenshots[[7]]
[[1]]$screenshots[[7]]$thumb
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/8adcf2d6a6cafc9c6b810f8359a3fedf-thumb_jpg.jpg"

[[1]]$screenshots[[7]]$original
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.angel.co/ae/386938/8adcf2d6a6cafc9c6b810f8359a3fedf-original.png"




[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] 385596

[[2]]$hidden
[1] FALSE

[[2]]$community_profile
[1] TRUE

[[2]]$name
[1] "Lariat "

[[2]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/lariat-1"

[[2]]$logo_url
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/385596-29de05d584176c3972da411aed5485f0-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1398260121"

[[2]]$thumb_url
[1] "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/385596-29de05d584176c3972da411aed5485f0-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1398260121"

[[2]]$quality
[1] 0

[[2]]$product_desc
[1] "Thus far, the internet has gone from discovery to search discovery, and then social discovery, but with little focus on recall. Remembering your digital footprint is difficult. We aim to solve that problem. Lariat is a cloud-based recall engine to securely recall information from any page in your search history instantly through intuitive keyword search, not just from page titles, but from the contents and context of the underlying pages.\r\n\r\nWrangle in the information you want, easier and faster."

[[2]]$high_concept
[1] "Recall your digital footprint on the web instantly"

[[2]]$follower_count
[1] 1

[[2]]$company_url
[1] "http://www.lariattech.com"

[[2]]$created_at
[1] "2014-04-23T13:17:47Z"

[[2]]$updated_at
[1] "2014-04-23T13:48:38Z"

[[2]]$crunchbase_url
NULL

[[2]]$twitter_url
[1] ""

[[2]]$blog_url
[1] ""

[[2]]$video_url
NULL

[[2]]$markets
[[2]]$markets[[1]]
[[2]]$markets[[1]]$id
[1] 4

[[2]]$markets[[1]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[2]]$markets[[1]]$name
[1] "digital media"

[[2]]$markets[[1]]$display_name
[1] "Digital Media"

[[2]]$markets[[1]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/digital-media"


[[2]]$markets[[2]]
[[2]]$markets[[2]]$id
[1] 12

[[2]]$markets[[2]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[2]]$markets[[2]]$name
[1] "enterprise software"

[[2]]$markets[[2]]$display_name
[1] "Enterprise Software"

[[2]]$markets[[2]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/enterprise-software"


[[2]]$markets[[3]]
[[2]]$markets[[3]]$id
[1] 59

[[2]]$markets[[3]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[2]]$markets[[3]]$name
[1] "open source"

[[2]]$markets[[3]]$display_name
[1] "Open Source"

[[2]]$markets[[3]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/open-source"


[[2]]$markets[[4]]
[[2]]$markets[[4]]$id
[1] 282

[[2]]$markets[[4]]$tag_type
[1] "MarketTag"

[[2]]$markets[[4]]$name
[1] "semantic search"

[[2]]$markets[[4]]$display_name
[1] "Semantic Search"

[[2]]$markets[[4]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/semantic-search"



[[2]]$locations
[[2]]$locations[[1]]
[[2]]$locations[[1]]$id
[1] 1620

[[2]]$locations[[1]]$tag_type
[1] "LocationTag"

[[2]]$locations[[1]]$name
[1] "boston"

[[2]]$locations[[1]]$display_name
[1] "Boston"

[[2]]$locations[[1]]$angellist_url
[1] "https://angel.co/boston"



[[2]]$company_size
[1] "1-10"

[[2]]$company_type
list()

[[2]]$status
NULL

[[2]]$screenshots
list()


[[3]]
[[3]]$id
[1] 385595

[[3]]$hidden
[1] TRUE
```

Finally, applying subsetting operation via logical index vector:

```
aa[data$startups$hidden == FALSE]
```

the result is an empty list (despite `hidden` = `FALSE` for the 1st and 2nd elements):

```
list()
```

Again, sorry about the output's size, but I had to retain the structure of the list.

**Considerations:**

According to R Project's "Introduction to R" (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors),

> "Subsets of the elements of a vector may be selected by appending to the name of the vector an index vector in square brackets. More generally any expression that evaluates to a vector may have subsets of its elements similarly selected by appending an index vector in square brackets immediately after the expression".

A the same time, according to Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R" (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html),

> "subsetting a list works in exactly the same way as subsetting an atomic vector".

Comment: @Roland: I followed your recommendation, but still not certain on what causes the error. I think I may need to use my original code to refer to the whole list, while subsetting via index vectors: `data$startups[data$startups$hidden == FALSE]`. However, this returns an empty list.

Comment: @Roland: I've used the "[" notation in my previous versions of the code: https://github.com/abnova/diss-floss/blob/master/import/getAngelListData.R, line 78. Why have you downvoted my question? Are you punishing beginner R users for their lack of experience and brief periods of confusion?

Comment: Please construct a minimal reproducible example. That will require showing the result of `dput(data)` for a cut down version of `data`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: How do I limit output for `dput`? Can't find the option for that.

Comment: You need to construct a small example that makes sense.  Then `dput(data)` will show it in reproducible form.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: OK, I will do my best. The reason I provided real data collection session's output is that I thought the problem might be related to the real data. I will try to come up with reproducible example.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Sorry about delay: site was in read-only mode and then I was offline. Finally, I was able to update my question with reproducible example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example data in the question is a list of length 3 which we shall call `L`.  Each of its components is itself a list and one component of each of these sublists is `hidden`.  We can extract the `hidden` components of the sublists into a logical vector called `hidden`.  Using that logical vector we can subset the original list `L` giving a new list containing only those sublists with a `hidden` component of `TRUE`.

```
hidden <- sapply(L, "[[", "hidden") # create logical vector hidden
L[hidden]
```

For the data provided we get a list with one component:

```
> length(L[hidden])
[1] 1
```

and if we knew that there were only one component then `L[hidden][[1]]` or `L[[which(hidden)]]` would give that single component.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! At this point, I'm interested in filtering out hidden startups, reflected by the root hidden attribute only. That was my intention, but the subsetting return an empty list. Why?

Comment: With the data provided the subsetting gives a length one list, not empty.  I have added to the example to show this.

Comment: I just tested your answer. It works perfectly! I was just curious about why my approach didn't work. I was assuming that R builds logical index vector recursively by default, hence my original code.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted your answer! It would be great, if you could clarify my confusion expressed in my previous comment. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: In terms of L the code provided in the question is `L[L$hidden]` but `L` has no component called hidden; therefore, `L$hidden` is `NULL`.  The fact that `L[[1]]`, `L[[2]]` and `L[[3]]` each have a hidden component is not relevant to `L` itself.

Comment: Hmm... My original code seems to be exactly as yours from the previous comment: `startups <- data$startups[data$startups$hidden == FALSE]`. Here `L` is substituted by `data$startups`.

Comment: The code in the question was equivalent to `L[L$hidden]` but the answer was `L[hidden]` where `hidden` is the result of the `sapply`.  These are different.  If you want everything not hidden then it is `L[ !hidden]` .

Comment: I understand now. I was assuming that I could use this semantics and R will understand it and will build the logical index vector automagically. I guess R's magical powers have limits, too :-). Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Data frames are indexed using [two numbers](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html). To only select rows, you need to do:

```
data$startups[data$startups$hidden == FALSE, ]
```

Comment: `data$startups` is not a data frame, but a **list**: `data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(startupData, simplifyVector = FALSE)`. Also see the `str()` output in my question.