# Management of R objects from different sources

Tags: r, object, attributes, datamapper

My dissertation **data collection process** involves extracting data from various open source software repositories and saving it as *R objects* for future analysis.

In order to prevent re-downloading and re-processing of already processed data (most of the data are archival), I use `digest()` to calculate *checksum (hash)* for data source URLs and then compare the incoming URLs with R data files named after the corresponding checksum. If a URL's checksum matches the existing R data file, I skip processing for this URL. I plan to use similar approach for another source, data from which are retrieved not via URLs, but via SQL queries. I thought about using `digest()` for calculating checksum of each data collection SQL query in this case.

However, my main question is **"What is best/optimal/correct approach to distinguish R objects when I'd like to load them back into R from data files?"**. I was thinking about the following two approaches to this:

1. In the process of saving data as R objects, dynamically create a **lookup table** with *URLs* and *corresponding checksums*. That would allow me to track back any checksum from R data file name to the corresponding URL and, thus, corresponding data file (table).
2. In the process of saving data, use `attr()` to store appropriate information (either full URL or just URL's file name for the URL-based data collection, or SQL query for the query-based data collection).

I see the benefit for the first approach (*lookup table*) in that it allows immediate lookup of needed URL or SQL query information, while the second approach (*attributes*) requires looping through the whole list for each data source in order to find matching information. At the same time, **attributes approach** seems to be better in terms of keeping metadata close to data itself, whereas **lookup table approach** moves it to the R code layer, which creates additional dependency.

Please advise on this situation and my thoughts.

Comment: I've already implemented both approaches that I mentioned (attributes and lookup table) - just to see how easy it is - but later realized that I can maintain lookup table not in R code, but as an R object, stored in `.RData` file. That would allow me to store metadata close to data as well as maintain different lookup tables for different data sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident that your data sources are static, you can use the following approach. Otherwise, the problem is much harder and it becomes unavoidable to re-download each time, unless the source provides a checksum for you (without pulling the full data).

In your directory of stored R objects, say in RDS format, you could adopt the convention of using the MD5 hash of the source to name the file. For example, if

```
> digest("http://google.com/someRfile")
[1] "bf01394aeea7b60cb0f5498c94d1b939"
```

Then you could store the serialized object present at that URL in the file with name `bf01394aeea7b60cb0f5498c94d1b939`. Checking for a cache hit is then a simple matter of using `file.exists`. If you wish to have metadata attached to the object itself, you can attach the URL as an `attr` to the object. Of course, this would create slow lookups because you would have to load in every date file and inspect its `attr`.

If you wish to avoid the lookup table idea (which is a good idea! Look into SQLite as a simple local store), you can still exploit the file system cleverly. Namely, instead of making the filename be the md5 hash, which is a one-way hash, use base64 encoding, so that it is two-way:

```
> library(RCurl)
> base64("http://google.com")
 [1] "aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20="
> base64("aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20=", encode = FALSE)
 [1] "http://google.com"
```

You can use the base64 encoded strings as your filenames, and now it is possible to easily determine the source of a serialized object by simply base64 decoding its filename. Note that this does not use a digest of the object at all, so you can still choose to attach metadata to it.

EDIT: You can even combine the ideas for something cleverer, removing the need for `attr` at all. Namely, you concatenate the MD5 digest of the R object with the base64 encoding of the source URL with a separator, say `-`. Then you can use `list.files(dir)` and regex to see if the file with a given source exists. From the other side, you can start with an R object, compute its MD5 digest, and easily determine whether or not it is already cached by using a different regex (one that finds the MD5 instead of the base64 encoding, e.g., `^[^-]+` instead of `[^-]+$`).

Comment: Robert, thank you for your answer! Actually, my initial implementation is based on `digest` and stores saved R objects in `.RData` files in `cache` directory. Then I just use `file.exists()` exactly like you described in your first suggestion. I didn't know that `base64` is a two-way hash, this advice is very interesting and will consider it, as it allows to avoid maintaining a lookup table. By the way, when you say it's "a good idea", what do you imply? Performance or some other criteria?

Comment: Just don't try to `base64` encode your R objects! MD5 size is always 32 characters, but `base64` is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of characters in your string.

Comment: Maintaining a table is a good idea because it's easier to use. You do not have to know about any conventions like with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I didn't intend to create a checksum of the data itself, just for URLs and SQL queries. It doesn't make sense for archival (static) data. In regard to maintaining local database, I'm trying to avoid it, as this would add additional dependency (not to mention maintenance overhead and performance overhead - I'm using `t1.micro` Amazon EC2 instance). I try to avoid additional dependencies to make my research as reproducible as possible.

Comment: Just saw your edit - thank you, I will think about this approach.

Comment: Robert, if you have experience with RCurl, cookies, session management and Perl, would you be so kind to take a look at this question (especially, Update 3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316469/debugging-rcurl-based-authentication-form-submission. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [UNF](https://github.com/leeper/UNF) package on GitHub. This is an implementation of the [Universal Numeric Fingerprint algorithm](http://thedata.org/book/unf-version-5-0), essentially a format-independent hash (or signature) of a dataset. This provides a unique signature for data (regardless of variable naming or the ordering of variables in a dataset). Any change at all yields a different UNF. You can use it to make sure two datasets are identical.

You could use it, for example, to create a list of UNFs for datasets  you already have, calculate the UNF on each new dataset and check that against the stored list of UNF signatures.

Full disclosure: I'm the package author.

Also note: As of today (2014/03/28), not all R data types are fully supported (namely, dates and times are treated as character strings, rather than being correctly handled per the UNF algorithm specification), but this may not matter for your purposes.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your answer! I will definitely take a look at the `UNF` package in detail. From my quick visit to your package's GitHub page, it's my understanding that `UNF` uses `base64` as a main fingerprinting algorithm under the hood. Since two main data sources I use contain archival data and of relatively large volumes, I don't think I need checksums of the data per se - checksums for URLs or SQL queries are enough for my purposes. But I will look into possible use cases for `UNF` in the future and in different parts of my project.

Comment: Thomas, I see that you use `Travis CI` integration for automating builds of your R packages. However, I don't see R as an valid (official) option in their Getting Started Guide (http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started). Do you use this method (http://yihui.name/en/2013/04/travis-ci-for-r) or that one (https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis)? Or something else? Thank you!

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I think craigcitro's is becoming the consensus version. It's under pretty active development.